# Find procedures referencing non-existing tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am wondering if there is a simple way to list all stored procedures that are referencing non-existing tables other than going through them 1 by 1 and looking at the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least few variants:

1. Using T-SQL:

   ```
   SELECT
      OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) AS [Procedure/View],
      referenced_entity_name AS [Missing object]       
   FROM 
      sys.sql_expression_dependencies
   WHERE 
      is_ambiguous = 0
      AND OBJECT_ID(referenced_entity_name) IS NULL
   ```
2. Paid tool **Redgate SQL Prompt**, by using [Finding invalid objects](https://documentation.red-gate.com/sp6/navigating-your-code/finding-invalid-objects). It has one month trial period

Comment: The `WHERE` clause I was thinking of using was `WHERE  ( referenced_database_name IS NULL
          OR referenced_database_name = db_name() )
       AND referenced_id IS NULL
       AND is_caller_dependent = 0 `

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a ready-made solution. For example, [Find Invalid Objects in SQL Complete](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/code-refactoring.html#find_invalid_objects) perfectly searches all calls to non-existent objects not only within the definition of stored procedures, but also for all database objects (triggers, views, functions, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

The other answer has the entities covered. To query the procs and their activity, use the code below. It shows activity since the last server restart. You can use this to find procs that have not been executed in years.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats
```

Comment: "You can use this to find procs that have not been executed in years." - this assumes that they also haven't restarted for years

Comment: @MartinSmith Yep, if the server was restarted this last weekend, this query would be mostly useless since it would possibly miss monthly/weekly reporting procs or other stuff that runs infrequently.